# how Insert the answers of questions into database with same radio button name?

Tags: php, ajax, php-7

how to pass the answers id to insert it into DB with **same name of the radio** button? because when I tried to insert the answers ids, the written code inserted the answers ids for the first if statement only

```
<div class="coursebox">
<?php 
echo '<div class="question-box" style="border-bottom: 0;"><h2>'; 
str('assess_exam'); 
echo'</h2></div>';

if($questions = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM evaluation_test WHERE year = 'half_year'")){
    echo '<form method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. sizeof($questions) .'" name="num_of_ques" />';
    $q_counter = 1;

    foreach ($questions as $q) {
        echo '<div class="question-box">';
        $ques = $l == 1 ? $q->q_en : $q->q_ar;
        echo '<p>'. $ques .'</p>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. $q->id .'" name="q_id[]" />';

        if($answers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM evaluation_answers WHERE q_id = $q->id")){
            foreach ($answers as $ans) {
                $a = $l == 1 ? $ans->ans_en : $ans->ans_ar;
                echo '<label><input type="radio" value="'. $ans->id .'" name="q_'.$q_counter.'_ans" required  checked />'. $a .'</label>';
            }
        }

        echo '</div>';
        $q_counter++;
    }

    echo '
        </form>
    ';
}

echo '<div class="question-box" style="border-bottom: 0;"><h2>';
str('assess_exam'); 
echo'</h2></div>';

if($questions = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM evaluation_test WHERE year ='one_year'")){
    echo '<form method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. sizeof($questions) .'" name="num_of_ques" />';
    $q_counter = 1;

    foreach ($questions as $q) {
        echo '<div class="question-box">';
        $ques = $l == 1 ? $q->q_en : $q->q_ar;
        echo '<p>'. $ques .'</p>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="'. $q->id .'" name="q_id[]" />';

        if($answers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM evaluation_answers WHERE q_id = $q->id")){
            foreach ($answers as $ans) {
                $a = $l == 1 ? $ans->ans_en : $ans->ans_ar;
                echo '<label><input type="radio" value="'. $ans->id .'" name="q_'.$q_counter.'_ans" required  checked />'. $a .'</label>';
            }
        }

        echo '</div>';
        $q_counter++;
    }

    echo '
        </form>
    ';
}

if(current_user_can('teacher')){
    echo '<button type="submit" name="save_report">'; echo $get_strings->save_report[$l]; echo'</button>';
}
?>

    </div>
```

**and here is the insert code**

```
if(isset($_POST['save_report'])) {
    $user_id = $_POST['profile_id'];

    if(!$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  multi_evaluation_answers WHERE user_id = $user_id AND type = 'evaluation-test' ")) {
        $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM  evaluation_test ");
        $q_array = $_POST['q_id'];        
        $num_of_ques = $_POST['num_of_ques'];

        for($i = 1; $i <= $num_of_ques; $i++) {
            $question_id = $q_array[$i-1]; 
            $answered_id  = $_POST['q_'.$i.'_ans'];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO multi_evaluation_answers(q_id, answered_id, user_id, type , test_type, answer_value )VALUES($question_id, $answered_id, $user_id ,'evaluation-test', 'age_move', (select ans_value FROM evaluation_answers WHERE id = $answered_id))";
            $wpdb->query($sql);
        }
    }
```

I need to insert the answers ids into database table with same name of the radio button, could you please guide me who to do it.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Prepare your queries, your wide open for SQLInjection  such as `$_POST['profile_id'] = '0 OR 1 --'`  Which makes your first query in the insert part into this:   `SELECT * FROM  multi_evaluation_answers WHERE user_id = OR 1 -- AND type = 'evaluation-test'` everything after the `--` is ignored as thats a comment in SQL.  OR 1, is always true and will return that entire table.  The point is I can edit your queries at will.  See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/

Comment: You should set the radio button value mate. Like https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio. Please see it. It will send the value with form post.